# Switching from dynamic Client ID to constant Client ID

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app, oauth, acs

I'm working on a **provider-hosted** **low-trust** Share Point App. I used to develop it with the Debugging Function of Visual Studio which created a new Client ID and Client Secret every time the debugging session was started.

```
2>  Web.config updated with Client ID 4437f542-4f58-47a3-81ee-9116a03c6a5c 
2>  Installation is in progress (00:00:00)
2>  ...
```

As I would like to provide this App via the Office Store I will need a constant Client-ID. So I created one via the [Seller Dashboard](http://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com) of Microsoft and updated my Web.config file.

[image: ClientID in the Seller Dashboard]

But now I'm getting this error message every time I start debugging the App with the new Client ID and Secret: `The app "i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|ClientID@b5990129-f04a-4d71-8a1f-5c958300a5e3" does not exist.`

[image: SharePoint Error Message]

The only thing I can see in that app String is the ClientID.

I tracked the calls in my App and found out that the first thing which is called in my App is the `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` function in the `SharePointContextFilterAttribute.cs` file.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }

    Uri redirectUrl;
    switch (SharePointContextProvider.CheckRedirectionStatus(filterContext.HttpContext, out redirectUrl))
    {
        case RedirectionStatus.Ok:
            return;
        case RedirectionStatus.ShouldRedirect:
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl.AbsoluteUri);
            break;
        case RedirectionStatus.CanNotRedirect:
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };;
            break;
    }
}
```

The first time `CheckRedirectionStatus()` returns `RedirectionStatus.ShouldRedirect` and after that the App is not called again. So I guess the SharePoint throws an error after that redirection.

How do I get a ClientID created in the Seller Dashboard working with my provider-hosted App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to edit the AppManifest.xml file under `<AppPrincipal>`

```
<AppPrincipal>
   <Internal />
   <!--<RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />-->
</AppPrincipal>
```

had the result that Visual Studio did not update the ClientID anymore when debugging. I changed it to

```
<AppPrincipal>
   <!--<Internal />-->
   <RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />
</AppPrincipal>
```

And it works fine in Deployment as well as in Debugging Mode :)

Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Helped me, too :)